# What does "conda create -n something anaconda" mean?

Tags: anaconda

I can understand What "conda create -n something python=3.7" does roughly.

But i can't understand "conda create -n something **anaconda**".

What does it mean? Why conda creates environment with anaconda?

Comment: In this context, think of anaconda as a pre-defined set of packages that make up the Anaconda scientific python distribution. This set of packages is maintained by the same-named company.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I can understand now.